# How to pass bounded generic type parameter class as argument

Tags: java, generics

how do you get class name of type parameter object?

Example: if function is

```
public <T extends Base> void convert(final T arg) {}
public <T> void method2(Class<T> typeParamClass) {}
```

How do i pass arg as `Class<T>` to method 2?

Error message when i try to pass arg.getClass()

Real Code Snippet

```
static <T> byte[] method2(T object, final Class<T> typeParameterClass) throws SerializationException {
}


static <T> T method3(final byte[] serializedObject, final Class<T> typeParameterClass) throws SerializationException {
        return (T) serializer.deserialize(typeParameterClass, Buffers.toBuffer(serializedObject));
    }
}

public static <T> T clone(final T object) {
    return method3(method2(object, object.getClass()), object.getClass());
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify, **what** *other* method?

Comment: @user3089214: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why does `method2` even declare a type parameter? It seems meaningless here.

Comment: would t.getClass() do what you need ? if not, why not ?

Comment: okaram: I tried it but getting IDE error: (java.lang.Class<T>) can't be applied to (java.lang.Class<capture<? extends java.lang.Object>>)

Comment: @user3089214, can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @andrew-tobilko, added screen shot in question.

Comment: @user3089214, with a code snippet, please

Comment: @andrew-tobilko, added it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public <T> void method2(Class<T> typeParamClass)
```

If you make the second method generic, you will be able to invoke that like

```
public <T extends Base> void convert(final T arg) {
    method2(arg.getClass());
}
```

There are no restrictions for `T` in the `method2` (`T extends Object`), so you are free to pass any `T` (including `T extends Base`).

As [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) noted, `T` is really meaningless here and the method can be defined simply:

```
public void method2(Class<?> typeParamClass)
```

---

UPDATE:

```
method2(object, object.getClass())
                       ^^^
```

The main issue here is that `getClass()` is a virtual method, returns a runtime type of an instance. It can not guarantee to return a `Class<T>` from the given `T`, but `? extends T` it can. To make it compiles, you have to change the signature to:

```
method2(T object, final Class<? extends T> typeParameterClass)
                              ^^^
```

Comment: I updated my question with correct signature of method2. I can't change method2 signature and method2(arg.getClass()); is not working

Comment: @user3089214: How is it not working? It appears to work in this test case: http://ideone.com/itdAIU

Comment: Gettinr error (java.lang.Class<T>) can't be applied to (java.lang.Class<capture<? extends java.lang.Object>>)

Comment: Updated question with real code. Hope it makes clear why T being used instead of ?

Comment: @user3089214, change `Class<T> typeParameterClass` to `Class<? extends T> typeParameterClass`, I will add an explaination

Comment: @user3089214, added, I hope it will help. is the problem solved?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko thanks, It solved the problem for method 2 but created problem for method3 now. Please help me in resolving method3 also. Should I change typeParameterClass in method3 to <?>

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [answer from Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40699242/1174961), the problem is the type erasure.

You are working with generics, `getClass` on `T` yields `Class<?>`, not `Class<T>`.

However, since we know that the type of `T` will always be `Class<T>`,
you can cast `object.getClass` to `Class<T>`, so you don't have to alter the method signature with redundant parameters.

So you could write:

```
public static <T> T clone(final T object) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // The type of 'object' will always be 'T'
    Class<T> typeClass = (Class<T>) object.getClass();

    return method3(method2(object, typeClass), typeClass);
}
```